# PySimpleGUI not looping as it should

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pysimplegui

I know it is a simple fix, but it's hard to find your own mistakes. I've been at it for a while and can't figure out why the window is behaving erratically.
I'm trying to capture voice events with speech-recognition (no problems here), and then count how many times the words was said (no problem here). The problem, however, is that so far it is capturing the first event, and then the it stops capturing it while the window stays open and the code runs in the background. I think it must be a while loop issue, but I can't figure out what or where exactly.
Thanks for your time in taking a look.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pyttsx3
import pyaudio
import speech_recognition as sr
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import sys


engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice',voices[1].id)
engine = pyttsx3.init()

def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

def take_command():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        print("Listening for command...")
        r.pause_threshold = 0.5
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        print("Recognizing voice...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-US')
        print(query)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("Unable to recognize. Try again please.")
        return "None"
    print(type(query))
    return query

if __name__ == "__main__":

    sg.set_options(background_color='#f3f6f4',element_background_color='#edeeef',text_color='black',text_element_background_color='#f3f6f4')
    layout = [[sg.Text('Hello Counter',font='Lucinda 16',size=(20,1))],
                [sg.Text(key='OUTPUT',font='Lucinda 12',text_color='green',size=(2,1),pad=(0,10)),sg.Text('Hello',font='Lucinda 14',size=(15,1),pad=(0,10))],
                [sg.Button('Count'),sg.Button('Exit',button_color=('white','#D33F49'))]]
    window = sg.Window('Hello Counter',layout,return_keyboard_events=True)

    counter = 0
    while True:
        event,values = window.read()
        if event == 'Exit' or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            sys.exit()

        if event == 'Count':
            query = take_command().lower()

            if 'hello' in query:
                counter +=1
                print(counter)
                window['OUTPUT'].update(counter)
            if "stop" in query:
                speak("Ok")
                sys.exit()
```

Comment: "the code runs in the background."  What does this mean?  Unless you're starting a thread or one of the calls you are making results in a thread being created, nothing is going to run in the background.  Maybe add a print both before the window.read and after so you know when you're asking PySimpleGUI for an event and when one is returned.

Comment: @MikefromPSG Hey MIke. What I mean is that technically when you close the window, the program stops, right? What's  happening is that the event is captured once, the the window is updated with the new count value, but then the window stops while still open, but the program is still running, I dont know if my explanation makes sense, but if you run the code, you'll see what I mean,

Comment: So you click the `Count` button again and there is no expected response? Or do you expect the voice recognition will run without clicking the `Count` button again and again?

Comment: @Claudio Yeah, I want to click Count once and let it listen for events continuously until either the user says Stop or click the Exit button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `while True` loop requires clicking the `Count` button again and again as the voice recognition starts only if the GUI reports a `Count` button click.
The code below should let your script behave as you expect it to behave. With the `Count` button click you enable the run of voice recognition function by setting `startListening` to `True` and call the voice recognition function from within `if startListening:` *and* you prevent freezing the GUI window by updating the PySimpleGUI text output element with a string value `str(counter)` instead of an integer `counter` value.

```
startListening = False

while True:
    event,values = window.read(timeout=200)
    if event == 'Exit' or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        sys.exit()

    if event == 'Count':
        startListening = True

    if startListening: 
        query = take_command().lower()
        if 'hello' in query:
            counter +=1
            print(counter)
            window['OUTPUT'].update(str(counter))
        if "stop" in query:
            speak("Ok")
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: Hey @Claudio, it still behaves the same. While I see the values being printed to console, the window itself does not get updated, except for the first time. After that, the windows seems to get stuck in a "Not responding state.

Comment: I have updated my answer, so the SimpleGUI text element gets a string `str(counter)` instead of an integer. Does it solve the issue?

Comment: It works. Awesome! Thank you for taking your time to help!

Comment: A cast to string isn't needed for `Text` element `update` calls.

Comment: @MikefromPSG : YES , as I just tested (Python3.9, PySimpleGUI 4.60.1) you are right, but ... somehow it solved the issue the OP had with his code ... Hmmm ...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your window.read command
from:

```
event,values = window.read()
```

to:

```
 event, values = window.read(timeout=200)
```

the timeout will allow the loop to run even if the user hasn't interacted with the window.

Comment: Hey RAllenAZ, thanks for the input. Same issue though...